# Как повернуть спрайт по оси z, по направлению Vector3?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Игра 2Д. Вычисляю направление, куда будет лететь снаряд от игрока к врагу и спавню снаряд таким кодом:

```
    private Vector3 fireDirection;

    private void GetEnemyPosition()
    {
            fireDirection = (enemy.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

            Instantiate(fireball, player.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Таким образом, **к примеру**, в fireDirection получаются значения `x:-0.8622108 y:0.5065495 z:0`

Собственно. запускаю снаряд таким образом. Летит он точно в сторону врага, а вот повёрнут всегда на `z:0`:

```
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(fireDirection * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

**Вопрос:** Каким способом можно найти угол между этими `х` и `у` и задать оси вращения `z` это значение(если это конечно так вычисляется), или каким ещё способом можно это сделать? Т.е, куда летит снаряд, туда и будет повёрнут его спрайт по оси `z`.

P.S И ещё доп. вопрос: есть ли разница, в производительности, качестве кода или ещё в чём-то, если в 2д игре я использую Vector3 вместо Vector2? Спасибо.

Comment: Vector to angle: `z = Mathf.Atan2(y, x)*Mathf.Rad2Deg`

Comment: Таким кодом снаряд поворачивается к врагу:  `transform.Rotate(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(fireDirection.y, fireDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);`, но летит почему-то в противоположную сторону от врага(а иногда даже в непонятно каком направлении). Если этот код убрать, то снаряд летит правильно. Применяю код один раз, а не постоянно в Update. Неужели поворот сбивает направление?

Comment: P.S Решил проблему, добавив в префаб снаряда пустой объект со спрайтом этого снаряда. Его transform и вращаю. Вопрос решен.